# Multiple Droppin on the MapView?

Tags: iphone

i have more than 100 coordinates (Latitude and Longitude), for that i want to add dropPin on MapView for all records.How it's possible can anybody tell me.I shall be thankful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Luckily there is a nice function!

```
[mapView addAnnotations:yourArray];
```

yourArray needs to contain MKAnnotation's or MKPinAnnotations.